# Factor several script and css tags into one file

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have several pages that require the same set of JS libraries (jQuery, d3, some other stuff) and CSS.  I really want to factor this repeated code out into one place.

How can I factor out all the "libraries" for JS and CSS **without** a server side language? I'm assuming there is a JS solution, like creating a "boilerplate.js" file that contains it all, then just getting that script.

```
<head>
  <!-- not page specific, factor this out. -->
      <!-- CSS library stylesheets -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../helpers/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">

      <!-- JS libraries -->
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- D3 -->
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <!-- Queue JS for async stuff -->
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/queue-async/1.0.7/queue.min.js"></script>
      <!-- crossfilter -->
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.1/crossfilter.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <!-- underscore -->
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <!-- bootstrap -->
      <script src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'>  </script>

   <!-- Page specific, do not factor this out -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myStyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
   <script>
     // Do some code that depends on all the above libraries
   </script>
</head>
```

If I was using PHP I could simply do a require(). If I was using Ruby on Rails I could have a partial for the specific pages. Etc. However, for reasons I won't go into, I can't use any server side stuff to help us out here.

Comment: RequireJS might do the trick for you: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: jme11 - I've used RequireJS but I don't believe it supports CSS

Comment: That's true, and it's not particularly elegant, but you can write a javascript module that loads your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I could just create my own large JS file with all the JS files required here. Then do the same thing with all the CSS required. At least this way it's only 2 files.

Only potential downside would be if loading 1 large JS file instead of 10 smaller JS files is slower since it's not parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add scripts and wait for them to load:

[Loading Scripts with jQuery](http://davidwalsh.name/loading-scripts-jquery)

What you can do is load a .js file that contains $.getScript() for all scripts you require.

Comment: I'm worried that with getScript(), the order of execution won't be maintained. Or if I set getScript() to "synchronous" I would GREATLY slow down the load speed of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use a preprocesser (such as ttree) and run it at build time (i.e. before you upload the static files that it outputs to your server) instead of run time (which requires a server side solution).

Comment: Unfortunately users are constantly uploading new static html files that the site will render - which rules out something running at build time. I don't want them to copy and paste 20 lines of required libraries and CSS, would rather just have 1 line thats marked like "dont touch this". Any other ideas?

Comment: How are the users uploading the files?

Comment: First they clone a repo / download a folder that has a base "site" for them to alter. Then they either reupload the folder through a form on our site, or maybe we do something convenient with github (tbd, I need to research whats possible). But the crux of this problem comes to the user being able to work on their site locally, so I can't be using any of my server side stuff, preprocessing etc.

Comment: I think that if you expect users to be technically proficient enough to be cloning git repositories, then it is pretty safe to ask them to run a build script.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like that wouldn't be simplifying people's lives though.  I'm really looking to make this base file as empty / simple as possible while they work on it.